# Angular 7 - boolean always evaluates to true

Tags: javascript, boolean, angular7

I have a boolean value in Angular 7 which I'm using to set a value in an object constructor. The boolean is passed as a parameter, which I store locally.

However, for some reason, the boolean always evaluate to true.

Here is the code in question:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.showPersonal = this.route.snapshot.params['showPersonal'];
    console.log("ngOnInit, this.id: " +  this.id);
    console.log("ngOnInit, this.showPersonal: " +  this.showPersonal);
    // if showPersonal is true, workRelated i.e. last item in constructor, is false

    if (this.showPersonal){
      console.log("showPersonal is true, setting work related to false")
      this.showWorkRelated = false;
    }
    else {
      console.log("showPersonal is false, setting work related to true")
      this.showWorkRelated = true; 
    }

console.log("this.showWorkRelated: " + this.showWorkRelated)
```

And this is the output:

```
todo.component.ts:28 ngOnInit, this.showPersonal: false
todo.component.ts:32 showPersonal is true, setting work related to false
todo.component.ts:40 this.showWorkRelated: false
```

I've tried a lot of different ways, but it always evaluates to true. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: What is `typeof this.showPersonal` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like your `this.route.snapshot.params['showPersonal']` return a string `false` so the `if (this.showPersonal)` is treated as true.

You should try to use `typeof this.showPersonal` to see which type the variable is.

Comment: Thanks - you're right about it being a string. I changed the type to string and then was able to do a comparison by string. Really annoying how Javascript changes a declared type like that - super-counter-intuitive.